# GCP external ip address range

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have few virtual machines on the cloud of Google.

My virtual machine running an application that connect to database server. The database server is protected with two types of authentications:

1. Password
2. IP addresses white-list

My problem is with - IP address. I need to define the allowed IPs manually on my database, in order to allow them to connect. Since I not controlling the external IP address (the changed dynamically), I looking to other solution.

Found [this script](https://gist.github.com/n0531m/f3714f6ad6ef738a3b0a) to get the whole range of Google IPs. But as the script writer said - this range of IP is changing in high frequency. Which is big problem - I can't trust this kind of solution.

It sound like I facing common problem - What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could in a more simple way use private ip in your CloudSQL.

This way your instances will be using their internal ip and not the external IP and as you should have defined a VPC you have full control over the range you should allow.

Comment: VPC - this what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In addition, please note you get the following [benefits using private IP to connect to Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip#benefits):

- Lower network latency: Private IP provides lower latency than public IP.
- Improved network security: Private services access traffic is never exposed to the public Internet.

Plus, you can follow these steps to [configure Private IP connectivity](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-ip) in your CloudSQL instances. Along with [VPC firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) and [network tags](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags) in order to allow/deny specific traffic in/out your GCP project and VM instances.